# How to reuse chained functions Javascript + Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, method-chaining

I'm using Typescript and creating a form validation library with chained methods, but I'm stuck trying to reuse functions because of the `this` return, I will exemplify in a simpler way:

```
const schema = {
  computer() {
    return {
      turnOn() {
        console.log('turn on')
        return this
      },
      openVscode() {
        console.log('open vscode')

        return this
      },
      work() {
        console.log('work')
        return this
      },
      turnOff() {
        console.log('turn off')
        return this
      }
    }
  },
  phone() {
    return {
      turnOn() {
        console.log('turn on')
        return this
      },
      takeSelfies() {
        console.log('take selfies')

        return this
      },
      callToMom() {
        console.log('call to mom')
        return this
      },
      turnOff() {
        console.log('turn off')
        return this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

everything works fine.

```
const devices = {
  iMac: schema.computer().turnOn().openVscode().work().turnOff(),
  iPhone: schema.phone().turnOn().takeSelfies().callToMom().turnOff()
}
```

but when I try to separate the repeated functions in another file, for example

```
const mixed = {
  turnOn() {
    console.log('turn on')
    return this
  },
  turnOff() {
    console.log('turn off')
    return this
  }
}
```

to reuse

```
const newSchema = {
  computer() {
    return {
      ...mixed,
      openVscode() {
        console.log('open vscode')

        return this
      },
      work() {
        console.log('work')
        return this
      }
    }
  },
  phone() {
    return {
      ...mixed,
      takeSelfies() {
        console.log('take selfies')

        return this
      },
      callToMom() {
        console.log('call to mom')
        return this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm stuck

[image]

I know this is because the `this` of the `mixed` object returns only the content itself, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

I thank you all!

Comment: I believe this is because `this` in `mixed` refers to `mixed`. Accordingly, `mixed` is unaware about other methods like `openVscode` or `work`. You should dynamically bind each `mixed` method with `newSchema.computer` `this`

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/oop-style#typed_inheritance, in my blog, you can find an example of typed mixin pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points made by captain-yossarian and Charlie about mixins are good and worth investigating if you want use them. However, here's a solution that doesn't require much refactoring of the original code:

```
const mixed = { /* same as before */ }

type AnyFn = (...args: never[]) => unknown

type SetReturnTypes<T extends Record<string, AnyFn>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => SetReturnTypes<T>
}

const makeMixed = <T>(obj: T & ThisType<T & typeof mixed>): SetReturnTypes<T & typeof mixed> => ({
  ...mixed,
  ...obj
}) as unknown as SetReturnTypes<T & typeof mixed>

const newSchema = {
  computer() {
    return makeMixed({
      openVscode() {
        console.log('open vscode')
        return this
      },
      work() {
        console.log('work')
        return this
      }
    })
  },
  phone() {
    return makeMixed({
      takeSelfies() {
        console.log('take selfies')
        return this
      },
      callToMom() {
        console.log('call to mom')
        return this
      }
    })
  }
}

newSchema.computer().turnOn().openVscode()
```

- `SetReturnTypes` makes all methods of `T` return the correct `this` type, assuming all these methods return `this`.
- `makeMixed` is a helper to create an object with `mixed` with the correct types. It uses [`ThisType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) so that the methods in `obj` have the correct `this` type:

```
makeMixed({
  doSomething() {
    this.turnOn() // would be a compile error without the ThisType
    return this
  }
})
```

An issue with this is that methods not returning `this` are incorrectly typed. If you want to ensure that all the methods return `this`, let me know and I may be able to come up with a solution for that.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgSwB4FMAmMC8MDeAoGGKAVwCcwB5MACgEpcDCZRIQAbFAOjZAHNqA5CXIxwA2o0KkUwsEQAWCCIwC+AGkayKAM210GTZuAjsuPfkLJyQu8ZJjTZCparwq8eKAE8ADihgAgmBeAGJy2NScUQCGpLwQAFwwYCgAbiikANoAuvSYAHwwxGAA1mAgAO5gHt5+MADKMgBKMlYAKr4oEAA8bTAoSFAoYGgQMC2gpGjd0KQIYLxqgcFh+YXY+ISZANIw8zAlKF42MG3ZSZExcYkwAAqx0XAyGT1tO9n5eYWNUC2yHX5Xvk3B4WNB4NFDgBZZDoLAwXpqfLUEAAIwAVkk+gAyU6KCAAlC9GC42ooE6IVBoT5JH5-dqdV4koidCmw6lYQrUTYwKKcSnoDSEPlo9FuejRMbFMqVOSShrNVrkQlM0ms7TwdnAvBg2ApCr1YDyFBwaLwnmgOA+YhDUj6HlSJVyU3Q9nc+yEEB+MAANQgoDQKHtHqYYNM3D4gi9wxgqX9IEDdkMhkcVmcymTMHUIYqIFIJWDmcIYY4EYsufzSaLqZEUHxIfchhUEkI2cIPnk4CD9AdDidENdVPdmagkJQjTY2gQXULRZLZkjQjHMAgKEn04gVczNbkdZcmbbyeA0TYbDaIChIDgs8z87LgmPp6IIHgV63yZ36Yb9mbrnceH1Q1jVNThLWtW06E4LQaFoKCrCoSDoMQ+CYM4aNfXjQNIPQv0A27ACUANI0TWiTgOy7ZDyAQ2CtF0SDHzPC8r0oyg6JoscJynGcaJQug8CAA)

Comment: thanks for answering! at TS Playground everything works fine, but at VScode it doesn't ... I can chain up a maximum of 3 methods then lose the intelisense, [see this image](https://i.ibb.co/QMhSRGS/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-18-a-s-13-16-40.png)

Comment: @YungSilva What version of TS are you using?

Comment: in fact I just copied your code and put it in a `.ts` file inside vscode, it was not linked to a project with typescript with dependency.

But now I did it correctly, I have a project with typescript in version @next `4.4.0` and I also tried `4.2.4` and I have a new problem now, when I chain 2 mixed methods, I lose the intelisense of the others . example: [se this image](https://i.ibb.co/VxTsMm7/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-18-a-s-18-51-18.png)

Comment: in TS Playground the same result results, if you chain 2 methods of mixed, the intelisense dies [see this image](https://i.ibb.co/c60KQfK/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-18-a-s-20-26-01.png)

Comment: @YungSilva Sorry about that! I've edited my answer. Try that out and see if it works. I changed `SetReturnTypes` to `{[K in keyof T]: (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => SetReturnTypes<T>}` (note the recursive instantiation of `SetReturnTypes`).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the pattern known as [Mixins](https://javascript.info/mixins) and is developed in typescript as [Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

The basic idea is to join two classes together to provide functionality similar to classical inheritance. It starts off with simple copying of object properties - but could be developed into functions that use closures to provide mixins at various levels.

Here is a proof of concept:

```js
utility = {foo: function() {return this}}
main = {bar: function() {return this}}

main = Object.assign(main, utility);

console.log(main.foo());
```

Comment: the example you provided with Object.assign does not work, the result is the same. "foo" returns only the utility object.

Comment: Please run the code. Calling of the `foo` returns an object with both foo and bar

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using Typescript. As you suggested, intelisense doesn't work [see in this image](https://i.ibb.co/0fW9R3H/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-18-a-s-13-00-16.png)

Comment: If your problem is intellisense - not the TS running itself, you should use an interface pattern with a class.

Comment: Another simple way to make it intellisense compatible is inheriting from a common base class.

Comment: exactly why i made this post, i'm stuck, can you provide an example in which intelisense works?